# Word ladder java

Tags: java, arraylist, stack, breadth-first-search

I am creating a word ladder with Stacks, ArrayList, LinkedList and Queues. We haven't went over HashMaps / Sets yet so I can not use it.

I am having a bit of trouble getting it to work.

The error I keep getting is NullPointerExecption on:

```
WordChain.getLink line 99
WordChain.solveA line 66
WordChain.main line 161
```

Word List:

```
dears 
fears
heart 
heart
monk 
perl
slow 
fast
blue 
pink
bluw 
pink
book
stone 
money
money 
smart
devil 
angel
fore
atlas 
zebra
babes 
child
mumbo 
ghost
train 
bikes
babies 
sleepy
brewing 
whiskey
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're getting the NullPointerException because you are trying to access an array that was never set.

On line 24, you declare an array:

`private static String[] usable;`

You don't actually give it a value anywhere in your code though.

Your main method starts, gets down to line 161, `startA();`, then control goes to the startA method.

Line 66 `String[] tempArray = getLink(start);` calls the getLink method.

Then, finally, at line 99, you have an if statement that checks:

`if(linkable(usable[i],n)){`

What's happening here is that it's trying to look at the i'th position in `usable`, but `usable` is still null (was never set to a value), so it's throwing a NullPointerException.

Comment: OH okay. Thanks! Didn't notice. Now I am getting a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. String index out of range: 4
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source). I updated the code.

Comment: That means that you're getting an error because you're trying to read the 4th character in a String that only has 3 characters. Set a stop point with your debugger and check out the state of variables as you get to that point.